# How to send RS-422A command

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing an application which have to interract with a device in RS-422A (9pin)
I would like to know which class I have to use?

NSOutputStream & NSInputStream?
or
NSFileHandle?

The first thing to do, it's to "select" which port is used to make the connection,
and then, send the bytes command.

If someone can light my way :-)

Thanks in advance
Arnaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial port programming on Mac OS X should be like on any other UNIXes. You can check this guide for example to get an idea:

- http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html#2_5_1